# How To Download Google Pegasus Library Model

Tags: python

I am a very newbie and currently working for my Final Project. I watch a youtube video that teach me to code Abstractive Text Summarization with google's Pegasus library. **It Works fine but I need it to be more efficient.**

So here is the code

```py
from transformers import PegasusForConditionalGeneration, PegasusTokenizer
tokenizer = PegasusTokenizer.from_pretrained("google/pegasus-xsum")
model = PegasusForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("google/pegasus-xsum")
```

**Everytime I run that code, it always download the "Google Pegasus-xsum" library which sized about 2.2 GB.**

So here is the sample of the code in notebook : https://github.com/nicknochnack/PegasusSummarization/blob/main/Pegasus%20Tutorial.ipynb

and it will running download the library like picture below :

[image: Picture]

**Is there any way to download the library first and then I saved it locally, and everytime I run the code it's just gonna call the library locally?**

**Something like caching or saving the library locally maybe?**

Thanks.

Comment: Did you install these? `pip install transformers` and `pip install sentencepiece`

Comment: I did, i just want to download the "google/pegasus-xsum" first and i run it locally

Comment: In addition, you need this `pip install torch torchvision`!

Comment: I install all the requirements and works perfectly, i just want to know how to download the "google/pegasus-xsum" first and i run it locally. (So The Source Code Could Be Efficient)

Comment: Downloading: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 2.12G/2.12G [03:34<00:00, 10.6MB/s]

After `pip install torch torchvision` and running your code again. I got the above and I run it again so it gives nothing and that obviously the model is already exist  locally. So how about you?

Comment: Oh, maybe I got it. `Please note that When pip install is used as a separate command to install the required package where as !pip install can be used inside a program as a statement which installs the required package while executing the program in which it is used.`

Comment: There it is, where can i find the 2.12GB downloaded data? you said it "exist locally", i need to know where it is.

Comment: So yeah just re-try running your notebook and instead of `!pip` use `pip` without `!`

Comment: i want to know the location of 2.12 GB downloaded model. where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mac**

Using **inspect** you can find and locate the modules easily.

```
import inspect
from transformers import PegasusForConditionalGeneration, PegasusTokenizer

tokenizer = PegasusTokenizer.from_pretrained("google/pegasus-xsum")
model = PegasusForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("google/pegasus-xsum")

print(inspect.getfile(PegasusForConditionalGeneration))
print(inspect.getfile(PegasusTokenizer))
```

You will get their paths sth like this

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/pegasus/modeling_pegasus.py
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/pegasus/tokenization_pegasus.py
```

Now, if you go and see what is inside the **tokenization_pegasus.py** file, you will notice that the model of **google/pegasus-xsum** is being probably fetched by the following line

```
PRETRAINED_VOCAB_FILES_MAP = {
    "vocab_file": {"google/pegasus-xsum": "https://huggingface.co/google/pegasus-xsum/resolve/main/spiece.model"}
}
```

where here if you open:

https://huggingface.co/google/pegasus-xsum/resolve/main/spiece.model

You will get the model downloaded directly to your machine.

#### UPDATE

After some search on Google, I've found sth important where you can get the used models and all their related files downloaded to your working directory by the following

```
tokenizer.save_pretrained("local_pegasus-xsum_tokenizer")
model.save_pretrained("local_pegasus-xsum_tokenizer_model")
```

Ref:
https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/14561

So that after running it, you will see the following being saved automatically in your working directory. So, now you can call the models directly but you need to search how...
[image]

Also, the **12.2GB** file that you wanted to know its path locally, it is being located here online

https://huggingface.co/google/pegasus-xsum/tree/main

And after downloading the models to your directory as you can see from the screenshot its name is **pytorch_model.bin** as it’s named online.

Comment: OMG Thanks for the answer, this is exactly what i need and helps me a lot.

The script says :
"model = PegasusForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("google/pegasus-xsum")"
and it download the model.

So lets say i did download the model locally to my machine, how can i call the model FROM my machine in my script? (so the script wont download the model again).

Comment: I am happy that’s helped you. Please note that on my machine the model was downloaded as I said earlier `ONLY ONCE` and whenever I run the script again, it only takes time to load it without any extra downloads. Now, let’s say we find a way to get your model to be called directly... I don’t recommend that since I think it is being checked each time by the above code if there is an error or update so you could know from the log.

Comment: i see... alright then, Thanks for your explanations.

Comment: @KenArya Cheers!! I've found something useful for you that does exactly what you need, please read the `UPDATE` above...